How to install an APK file from another app
I'm trying to design a simple app that launches installation of a previously download apk file (for update purpose of another app).
This app has one button to launch the update.
Here is what i found and tried but without success :
        string s = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath;
        string path = s + "/TPAndroid-Signed.apk";


        Android.Net.Uri apkUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(path);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.Action);
        intent.SetDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantPrefixUriPermission);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantPersistableUriPermission);
        StartActivity(intent);

Thank you for your help.

Check if your installer app has permission Also show relevant logs in your question.

here is the error message :

Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException
Message=No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN dat=/storage/emulated/0/Download/TPAndroid-Signed.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x100000c1 }

Have you seen: intent to install apk on android N

yes, but i think its in native android app, not with xamarin. I'll try to do the same with android studio. thank you
